# css layout fails in ie, has minor bug in opera. help?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I devised a layout based on [this one](http://www.alistapart.com/d/holygrail/example_4.html) (from [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail)) - I made freely rearranging the divs possible for a bit of SEO. You can see what I did [here](http://poland.inbulgaria.org/perhaps/holy.htm) ([css](http://poland.inbulgaria.org/perhaps/style.css)).

As it is, my layout has one minor bug - in Opera, the viewport doesn't expand to accommodate the footer (i.e. the scrollbar doesn't appear if only the footer is out of view). Otherwise, it works flawlessly in Opera 11, Firefox 4 and IE 8. However, when I uploaded it to the [site](http://poland.inbulgaria.org) I'm making it for, ([layout css](http://poland.inbulgaria.org/layout.css)), it turned out that the page looks broken in IE - the left column appears on top of the middle one, and the header doesn't appear until I fiddle with the left column's parameters in IE's developer tools.

So, can anyone help me figure out what breaks the page? I know that this question is more suited for doctype.com, but I can't login there for some reason.

However, I would prefer to have the divs in my HTML source in this order:

1. Content
2. Footer
3. Left column
4. Right column
5. Header

**I do not need propositions for new layouts. I am trying to understand why [this](http://poland.inbulgaria.org/perhaps/holy.htm) works in IE and [this](http://poland.inbulgaria.org) doesn't.**

Comment: What they really want is the source portion that is causing the problem specifically. Sure we can view source, but I certainly don't want to swim in shark infested css waters looking for a magical bug.

Comment: Well, if I knew what caused the bug, I probably could've sorted it out :/ And in posts like that of @boss, one really can't be certain of the poster's intention.

Comment: Neither worked in IE. In both examples, the header and footer were both missing in the IE version. When looking at the source and the style sheets, you have classes that aren't defined all over the place, empty divs that do seemingly nothing. That whole thing is a complete mess. If you want one to look like the other, you need to go back to basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When faced with a difficult engineering problem, be it programming, web design, or electronics, often the most successful method (for me at least) is the 'outside-in' method. One of the most difficult thinks about it is making yourself use it, since it's "only a little tweak somewhere" that you'll make and fix everything... When I spend a good while looking for that right tweak, I know I should change my approach.

So, starting from scratch, I rebuilt a copy of index.php, pasting bits from the broken original in order to figure out what breaks stuff.  And, sure enough, it turned out that the culprit was... the DOCTYPE, something I never paid much attention to - since I only recently started working on webpages as part of my job, caring about compatibility, etc. I slapped a XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype instead of the original HTML, and it worked like a charm.

Thanks to everyone who helped and especially to @Magnum for his effort.

(:

Answer (score 1):

Solution two for SEO:

```
  <div id=siteBox>
  <div id=center class=column>
    <h1>This is the main content.</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla.</p>
  </div>
  <div id=header>This is the header.</div>
  <div id=left class=column>
    <h2>This is the left sidebar.</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla.</p>
  </div>
  <div id=right class=column>
    <h2>This is the right sidebar.</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla.</p>
  </div>
  <div id=footer>This is the footer.</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could be. I actually ran this test, but disregarded those warnings. They're artifacts from the old hackish layout, mostly.

Comment: My advice would be to never ignore the warnings unless it is impossible to fix, make sure you also validate your CSS as well. Any problems drop me a line. :)

Comment: I'm looking at it now for you, why have you got two style sheets with some of the same references in?

Comment: Well, since I'm changing the layout a lot, I though that I should put text styling, background colors, and the stuff that doesn't change, into a separate file.

Comment: It probably will - but I'm trying to have an arbitrary order of divs in my source. What I'm trying to understand is why [->this<-](http://egasimus.hit.bg/holy.htm) works and the site doesn't.

Comment: ^ Your link doesn't work. Part of the problem is that you have alot of Divs that aren't called in the css, so IE can't position something that doesn't have a style attached to it, weather it's labled or not. My version works because all sections are called in the css.

Comment: Damn, my mistake. I forgot that the site where I hosted it isn't visible outside of Bulgaria. [Here's a working link.](http://poland.inbulgaria.org/perhaps/holy.htm)

Could you point out examples for divs not called in the CSS?

Comment: If you have your divs in a logical order line my example it makes it alot easier to edit. :)

Comment: But I don't want them in an order that's logical to humans, but in one appealing to search engine robots - that is, content on top. And my header is remarkably lacking in terms of content.

I know I'm probably overestimating the value of this trick, but I guess every little bit helps. (:

Comment: You must remember that search engine robots are textual based and can't see or read images, if you turn off your css that is how the robots will read your site. It doesn't matter, in my oppinion, in which order the content is placed, this will not effect the quality or score you would get from the robots. If you test both the page that works and the page that doesn't you will see the content displays in the same order. :)

Comment: My sources:
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/markup-hierarchy-advantages-seo/
http://www.seoracle.com/seo-tutorial-optimization/on-page-seo-factors-keywords

I'm really not looking to revise my concept, but fix the site's behavior in IE. If the bare layout works, then there's something in the content that breaks it. I can't figure out what it is, though - that's why I called for the hive mind's expertise.

Comment: See my updated answer, this is taking into account the way you want to have your divs for SEO. You can use the same css as your example from list apart.

Comment: Well, that's not the exact order, otherwise, that's how the page is (supposed to be) laid out anyway. I guess I'll try to redo the layout from scratch and see if that helps.

Still, what are the uncalled DIVs you mentioned?

Comment: Go through your main page, make a note of all of the divs then do a find in your css. According to the document that you linked up the code is in the same order but with the extra column.

Comment: I had given up - then I redid a page from scratch and found out that the doctype was breaking IE support. Thanks for the help (:

Answer (score 1):

While A-List-Apart is one of my favorite sites, I've found that sometimes their suggested css is not always as cross-browser compatible as one might like it to be. The same layout can be found by Mathew James Taylor that is cross-browser compatible and requires no javascript to pull off. Get ready to wade hip-deep in css, though. This is the css template I use for most of my basic layouts now. I've found it to be extremely flexible once you have analyzed how all of the containers fit together.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm

Comment: That's the layout I started out with a couple days ago. (:

My major concern is about this SEO thing - if possible, not only putting the middle column before the sides, but actually ordering the divs like this: content, footer, left column, right column, header. I'm still trying to do this - if not, I'll go back to MJT's layout.

Comment: Also, my modified ALA layout seemed to work in IE before I uploaded it to poland.inbulgaria.org.